# Illegal string offset in array

Tags: php, arrays

I use a library for Synchronize a local WebSQL DB to a server specifically https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync.
I use PHP: 5.4.7,
When I try to get the array values ​​as follows, I get the message

Illegal string offset 'clientes'

the $obj var is:

```
 Array
(
    [info] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [clientes] => Array
                (
                )
            [conceptos_gastos] => Array
                (
                )
        [formaspago] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [idFormaPago] => 10
                        [FormaPago] => qwerqwe
                        [Dias] => 1
                        [Cuotas] => 1
                        [last_sync_date] => 
                    )
            )
        [listaprecios] => Array
            (
            )
        [producto] => Array
            (
            )
        [repartidores] => Array
            (
            )

        [tipodocumento] => Array
            (
            )

        [vehiculos] => Array
            (
            )
        [zonas] => Array
            (
            )
    )    
)
```

this is the loop

```
foreach ($obj as $row => $value) {
echo $row["clientes"]["fomaspago"]["FormaPago"];
}
```

eternally grateful for any help

Comment: Seems like `data` should be your first dimension in your array.

Comment: use $obj["data"] instead of $obj in foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all but the only way that worked was as follows:

```
foreach($obj->data->formaspago as $formaspago) {
  print " id ".$formaspago->idFormaPago; 
  print " Formapago ".$formaspago->FormaPago; 
  print " dias ".$formaspago->Dias;
  print " cuotas ".$formaspago->Cuotas; 
  print " lastsyncdate ".$formaspago->last_sync_date; 
}
foreach($obj->data->clientes as $formaspago) {
  print " id ".$formaspago->IdCliente;
  print " Cliente ".$formaspago->Cliente; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems to be

```
$row["data"]["clientes"] // which is an empty array
```

or

```
$row["data"]["formaspago"][0]["FormaPago"] // which should output "qwerqwe"
```

Comment: I tried the following:   foreach ($obj as $row => $value) {
   $row["clientes"]["fomaspago"][0]["FormaPago"];
}   and still the same error message      also    $row["data"]["formaspago"][0]["FormaPago"]

Answer (score 0):

The element $row["clientes"]["fomaspago"]["FormaPago"]; does indeed not exist - look at the output: the 1st row "info" does not have that index, the 2nd row "data" has "clientes" and also "fomasgapo", but does not have a "clientes" "fomasgapo".
You need to either structure your data differently or loop through it differently...

Comment: i tried $row["data"]["formaspago"][0]["FormaPago"] and still the same error , also $row["data"]["formaspago"]["FormaPago"]

Comment: Yes, because these elements are not there! BTW, you can avoid the error by checking if (isset($row...index...)) beforehand...